# Raspberry pi - android video streaming

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi

I am trying to develop a program which connects raspberry pi and android application over global network (aka they are in different network. i.e. User from NY is using Android, LTE and raspberry is connected to wifi, located in Oregon )
So far, I succeeded connecting them via Pusher service for TCP connection for controlling GPIO pins.

However, I just can't figure out how to establish live streaming in raspberry pi (pi camera).

I tried Youtube live streaming, however, I had to enable adsense from youtube and to enable it, I have to reach over 4000 watch hours which is overwhelming effort for small project...

Idea I had in mind is..

1. Periodically upload photo taken from raspberry pi to Amazon S3 and download to Android, making it look like a video..
2. Build a web server that hosts live streaming and receive static IP.

If there's a service that hosts video live streaming, please do let me know..

Any help would help me greatly! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use NGINX server to publish your stream as RTMP. Then you can play this stream on your android app using rtmp android client

Comment: What do you say on utilizing Amazon Kinesis video stream? Your suggesting looks tempting as well but publishing NGINX server to public domain seems a bit complicated || unstable work.. Thank you very much !!

Comment: why it is unstable do you think ? And it is also opensource no need to pay to amazon

Comment: Wow so NGINX allows me to publish public domain (In other words view live streaming from different network) without extra charge??

Comment: My project requires that the live stream should not be only available to local host... Does RTMP supports this??

Comment: Not rtmp, nginx provide that as a server. Please take a look this : https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much. I browsed around and turns out I might be able to embed VLC player in android app and stream video! Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: so pls accept my answer tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NGINX - RTMP server, please look here : https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

Also If you want to play your rtmp over android, you need a rtmp/rtsp client for your app. You can find it here: https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java

So no need to pay anywhere

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to make nginx server and do streaming. However, I still cannot figure out how to make it accessible from outside of network.. I read some advice regarding proxy or port forwarding but didn't work.. Do you have any suggestion on this? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I am following the example below...
https://github.com/Tomtomgo/raspberry_livestream